# How to setup Flash Builder compiler constants ONCE for multiple projects in the same Workspace?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash-builder, workspace, multiple-projects, compile-time-constant

Is there any way to link some Flex or AS3 compiler options so that multiple projects in the same workspace can share the same Compiler Constants values?

[image]

Basically, I will need to frequently change the "LANG_ENG" and "LANG_FR" to **true** and **false**, for 3 or more projects. Instead of having to go in each one, I'd like a *one-change-affects-all* solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question ties-in with this one: [How can I use relative-paths in Flash Builder's "-load-config=..." compiler argument?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24293459/how-can-i-use-relative-paths-in-flash-builders-load-config-compiler-argu?stw=2)

[image]

As for the format, you can write something along these lines:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<flex-config>
<compiler>
    <define append="true">
      <name>COMPILE::LANG_ENG</name>
      <value>false</value>
    </define>
    <define append="true">
      <name>COMPILE::LANG_FR</name>
      <value>true</value>
    </define>
</compiler>
</flex-config>
```

Which in this case, would set the *LANG_FR* to **true**, *LANG_ENG* to **false**

Answer (score 0):

No the Compiler Constants are defined per project in FlashBuilder. You could simplify the edit ing process by using ANT and having multiple build files for a project to avoid opening the project properties. Also you could reuse most of your build file(s) between projects.

Comment: hmm what about setting the -load-config+=some_config_file.xml compiler argument? I think that would be the way to go, but I'm not sure of the correct XML format to write a valid Flash Builder config file.