# How can I use relative-paths in Flash Builder's "-load-config=..." compiler argument?

Tags: flash, compiler-construction, flash-builder, configuration-files, relative-path

Not sure if this is a Windows 8/8.1 issue only, but seems like any "../" relative-paths gets stripped out of the resolved path when Flash Builder attempts to compile a project.

Is there a special syntax to include relative paths? Is there one way to set it so it works both on a Mac and Windows system?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if this was pre-configured by another developer on our team, but seems like this Linked-Resource path is auto-generated PER projects (not created at the Workspace level), so you can use PROJECT_LOC and PARENT_LOC.

[image]

Someone can correct me if I'm wrong, this may have been a ${tag} that was manually created, but I can't see how that would happen since it works on two separate systems (Mac and Windows) with quite varying root folders.

Hope this can help others too!